# Northbridge Heatsink Fell Off Motherboard

Tags: motherboard, desktop, heatsink

I have an Asus CG5290 and the northbridge heatsink popped off, right after that it shut down. Turned it back on and it said the northbridge was hot then started it again and the other was saying hot too. It has some sort of pins & springs that hold the northbridge on the board which broke off, I assume melted. I put it back on and then started it up again and the fans just keep running high. It starts and runs but it sounds like it's running high. Is it fixable?

Comment: On behalf of SU, I apologize for whoever voted you down without explanation.  It's a good question!

Comment: If they *melted* I'd be worried as heck. Even nylon has a pretty high melting point. A picture of the board and broken bits would be nice for post mortem purposes.

Comment: Beside cleaning the northbridge and applying new thermal paste, you need pressure to squeeze the thermal paste into all the tiny surface imperfections.  You need the pressure applied by the springs for proper thermal contact.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the mounting mechanism is actually broken, an alternative is to use an adhesive thermal compound (e.g. [Arctic Silver Thermal Adhesive](http://www.arcticsilver.com/arctic_silver_thermal_adhesive.htm)).  Follow the instructions included with the product.

I usually clean off the old compound with 99% isopropyl and cotton swabs--both are inexpensive and easily found at any drug store.